# How can I better understand Thevenin resistance?

Tags: resistance, thevenin

On the internet, it is mentioned that Thevenin's Theorem states that "Any linear circuit containing several voltages and resistances can be replaced by just one single voltage in series with a single resistance connected across the load". But I don't understand why.

[image]

If I didn't misunderstand, you calculate Rth by combining 3 ohm and 6 ohm, and then adding 2 ohm with the previous result, and finally add that with 4 ohm. And that's how you calculate total resistance when the electricity flows from + to -, which are on the right side.

What I want to ask is the reason why you suppose that the electricity flows from + to - even if it's not true because the electricity flows clockwise in this situation.

Comment: I don't understand the actual question in the last phrase.

Comment: What's confusing? Most EE's would regard *current flow* as clockwise here. For example, *current flow* through the 3-ohm resistor is from left to right. Similarly, *current flow* leaves this one-port's "+" terminal, and returns to its "-" terminal through a load resistor - isn't that clockwise?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem):

> "For any linear electrical network containing only voltage sources, current sources and resistances can be replaced at terminals A–B by an equivalent combination of a voltage source Vth in a series connection with a resistance Rth."

The Thevenin equivalent circuit is only equivalent from the perspective of the input terminals.  Whatever happens inside the "black box" of the actual circuit is irrelevant; the circuits will, from the perspective of the input terminals, have the same linearly related Isc and Voc.

Your calculation of the Thevenin resistance starts correctly, but your terminology is imprecise.  You begin by setting the voltage sources to zero, "shorting" them.  This puts 3 and 6 in parallel, which is 2 Ohms.  The 2 Ohm resistor is in series with the 2 Ohm combination, so their combination makes 4 Ohms.  Finally, the 4 Ohm resistor is in parallel with the rest, so the Thevenin resistance is 2 Ohms.

Comment: I mean, it's not my calculation actually. I don't understand why it puts 3 and 6 in parallel even if the current flows clockwise

Comment: That has to do with superposition theorem, which is very closely related.  Yes, current from the 9V source in the circuit flows clockwise through that pair of resistors, but you are trying to find the equivalent resistance as seen "looking into " the Vo terminals.  (Ideal) resistors don't change value if current flows through them so you can examine their contribution to the equivalent resistance separately from any current or voltage sources.  Since the sources are also assumed to be ideal, you can set them to 0 since they will be the same regardless of what happens at Vo.

Comment: I've just seen A video about the superposition theorem, but I don't find it helpful. In what sense do you mean that it has to do with superposition theorem?

Comment: It means that you can analyze certain aspects of the circuit as separate stand-alone problems and add them together to obtain the entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thevenin voltage/resistance refers to replacing everything in the box as shown:

[image]

With a voltage source (which will be lower than 9V) and a series resistance (which will be less than 4 ohms). From the viewpoint of whatever you connect to the terminals Vo.

It does not explain what goes on in the box. For example, the box will get warm in the non-Thevenin original form (with output open) because there is current flowing through all the resistors.

The calculation of resistance is 4||(2+ (6||3)) ohms. You also need to calculate the open-circuit voltage for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not refute other answers, which make good points. Am addressing conditions that cause current flow in this network to **reverse**. And add a quirky condition that has bitten me...

Any **resistive** load that connects to the two output terminals cannot change current direction. Through every component, current flows clockwise - including any **resistive load** of any value.

But you are allowed to connect not just resistors, but current sources, and voltage sources too. With these, it is possible to change direction of current flow.
Here's an example setup where a voltage source is connected to this black box...

If we set the external voltage source V3 to zero volts, current flows always clockwise. However, NO current flows through the black box's \$4 \Omega\$ resistor (because it is shorted by the external 0V voltage source...all the 1.5A current flows into voltage source V3:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBZ4m9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Nothing so far violates the requirement of Thevenin/Norton for linearity, yet we have the rather odd situation that V3 must *accept* current, rather than *supply* current...that 1.5A current flows *into* V3 rather than *out of* V3.

Many (most) designers of voltage sources expect that they will be a **source of current** - that is, current will always flow *out of their supply*. This is true of most linear regulator integrated circuits - all guarantees are void if current tries to flow backwards. In this example, current in V3 is flowing "backwards".
So if you try to actually do this as an experiment, you may find that no matter what you do, the voltage supply that serves as V3 **cannot be set to 0V!**.

---

Now we turn up the voltage knob on V3 so that current flow **into V3** reduces to zero amps. This voltage will be equal to \$V_T\$ (Thevenin equivalent voltage). Resistors R1,R2,R3,R4 are all linear, and don't care which direction current flows through them...the Thevenin/Norton equivalent resistances (R5,R6) are similarly linear.

As we keep increasing V3 above \$V_T\$, current direction through the resistors reverses (not all at the same time). V3 should be operating properly now that it is a source of current, forcing current *into the black box*.

As V3 increases further, it will reach a voltage where current direction reverses into BAT1 (9V). If this were a battery, it would now be charging, rather than discharging.
If BAT1 were an electronically-regulated 9V voltage source (like V3), we would have a problem, where this black box behaves non-linearly as V3 rises above this critical voltage...and our THEVENIN/NORTON equivalents fail.